# Сортировка пузырьком

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Какой массив из 10 ячеек будет сортироваться "Пузырьком" за меньшее количество перестановок, чем "быстрой сортировкой"?

```
A=[4,1,8,9,3,7,2,10,6,5]
B=A[::]
N=len(A)
k=0
def qSort ( A, nStart, nEnd ):
    x=0
    if nStart >= nEnd: return
    L = nStart; R = nEnd
    X = A[(L+R)//2]
    x=x+1
    while L <= R:
        while A[L] < X: L,x=L+1,x+1
        while A[R] > X: R,x=R-1,x+1
        if L <= R:
            A[L], A[R] = A[R], A[L]
            L += 1; R -= 1
            x=x+1
    qSort ( A, nStart, R )
    qSort ( A, L, nEnd )
    return x
N = len(A)
for i in range(N-1):
  for j in range(N-2, i-1 ,-1):
    if A[j+1] < A[j]: 
      A[j], A[j+1] = A[j+1], A[j]
      k=k+1
print('Количество перестановок "Пузырьком":',k)
print('Количество перестановок "Быстрой сортировкой":',qSort(B,0,N-1))
```

Comment: Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что `B=A` не работает так, как Вы задумывали. Все дальнейшие замеры бессмысленны.

Comment: Чтобы был более понятен комментарий выше: при такой инициализации вы не создаёте копию массива `A`, а просто создаете еще одну переменную, указывающую на тот же объект -> все операции над `A` это операции и над `B`. Напишите `B=[4,1,8,9,3,7,2,10,6,5]`

Comment: Если говорить об улучшенной быстрой сортировке (где одинаковые элементы не меняются местами), то не существует массива, который бы сортировался за большее количество перестановок, чем при пузырьковой. Но если одинаковые элементы будут меняться местами, то на почти отсортированных массивах, это возможно. На каких именно тоже зависит от алгоритма, а точнее от того, как будет выбран опорный элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Простой эксперимент и здравая логика подсказывают, что это будут массивы, которые практически отсортированы, либо массивы малой длины. Для того, чтобы провести этот эксперимент, давайте будем генерировать массивы различной длины и для каждой последовательности запомним число перестановок. Все те, которые изначально отсортированы выбросим как тривиальный случай. Мы можем нагенерировать очень много таких последовательностей. В конце выберем только те из них, для которых справедливо "число перестановок bubble_sort < число перестановок q_sort":

```
import numpy as np

perms = []

for i in range(1000):
    n = np.random.randint(8, 100)  #  случайный размер массива
    A_ = np.random.randint(0, 1000, n).tolist()  #  массив
    if all(A_[i] <= A_[i+1] for i in range(len(A_)-1)):  #  проверяем, что массив не отсортирован (не тривиальный случай)
        continue

    A = A_[::]
    B = A[::]
    N = len(A)
    k = 0

    for i in range(N-1):
      for j in range(N-2, i-1 ,-1):
        if A[j+1] < A[j]:
          A[j], A[j+1] = A[j+1], A[j]
          k=k+1
    b = qSort(B,0,N-1)
    if b < k:
        continue
    perms.append((k, b, A_))

print(sorted(perms, key=lambda el: el[0] - el[1]))
```

Пример ответа:

> [(7, 8, [434, 110, 109, 339, 487, 919, 846, 644]), (7, 7, [333, 282,
>   17, 71, 502, 390, 425, 535]), (9, 9, [9, 163, 754, 75, 390, 993, 545,
>   790, 681])]

**Замечание**. Ответы для случайных массивов длины более 10, я не нашёл (их можно найти для тривиальных или почти тривиальных случаев)